# Birt report parameter not fully display

Tags: report, birt

I've a problem while using BIRT report developed tool, the value in parameter is not fully shown. The parameter is display from a dataset (just a simple select statement), the output is correct, just the the dropdown list not fully display the value.

The example below actually is a list of value, but some of the value is very long, the parameter cannot fully display it.

Hope someone can help me or give me some idea to solve this, thanks![image]

Comment: can you confirm that on Data Set config dialog, on the Preview tab you can see full length values?

Comment: @Miki, yes, it shown the full length values, i was wondering is there any configuration I need to modify?

Comment: I found link on BIRT Actuate forum of guy stating that limit in parameter value is bug. Though its Actuate not "plain" BIRT I would guess its bug in here too. Check whole topic http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/20508-max-report-parameter-size/?p=68438

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a CSS rule. You can't make the width of a combobox dynamic depending on the content of select items, but it can be adjusted for your requirements.

Edit this file: *[birt viewer home]/webcontent/styles/style.css*

And increase "width" attribute as you like, for example set it to 350px.

```
.birtviewer_parameter_dialog_Select {
  font: Verdana;
  font-size: 8pt;
  width: 250px;
}
```

You might have to restart your Eclipse or Application server to take it into consideration, and clear your web-browser caches.